# What was the maneuver called when an infantry co. fired in two different directions while advancing?

Tags: military, napoleonic-wars

When a Napoleonic-era infantry company was taking fire from front and rear, what is the maneuver called where they covered their rear while advancing forward?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to military science and by history.

Comment: Are we perhaps talking Napoleonic-era unit tactics, or are we talking modern-day? (Gone ahead and edited to assume the former, as the latter is off-topic.) That's likely the case, since as near as I can tell, named parade-ground manuvers [became militarily obsolete](https://www.britannica.com/topic/drill-military) around the time of the Civil War and WWI.

Comment: I suspect the term is '_fire and manoeuvre_' (or '_fire and maneuver_', if you prefer).  The term remains in use, and the direction from which the company is/was taking fire, relative to their objective, is/was normally irrelevant.

Comment: Hollow or Infantry Square is probably what you are referring to. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infantry_square

Comment: @Tombo - I think you are correct there. However, the question seems to be asking about the name(s) of the parade-ground maneuver, not the name of the formation used to perform them. I say "parade-ground", but in the Napoleonic era, parade ground training was intended to practice maneuvers that the unit would actually be expected to perform under fire.